# Multiple Pagination by Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

How to implement more than one pagination , say two or three on the same page showing different records using Codeigniter. I had tried using the default pagination library but it does not work out.

Would appreciate if this question is answered in detail and using simple explanation(I being a mediocre Programmer)

Comment: I don't know what is the use case but good question. You may try dig in to the code and see if create_links accepts any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before, but I guess you could create n-different $configs and use the $this->pagination->initialize(); each time to initialize the paginations.

Something like this (not tested):

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config1['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config1['total_rows'] = 200;
$config1['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config1);
echo $this->pagination->create_links(); 


$config2['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config2['total_rows'] = 200;
$config2['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config2); 
echo $this->pagination->create_links();

$config3['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config3['total_rows'] = 200;
$config3['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config3); 
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Have you checked it?

Comment: OP mentions on "same page" that means I guess that he wants to have 2 or more pagination "links" at the same time. "1,2,3,4,5..." and another one just next to it "20,21,22..." (or in different position)

Comment: Lykos...thanks for your i/p.... but as per enquiry with some experienced developers...they saying that the default pagination library aint gonna work out.They suggest to use ajax...But im in confused state as to how should I go about it?? The code you have given has been used(resembles somewhat) by one of my colleagues but it doesnt work out....

Comment: Kyslik... not like that.... I expect two(or say three) different pagination tables with entirely different records and different number of page links.These tables would be on the same page and each table would get paginated independently.

Comment: @Saurabh If you are going to do it with Ajax, I guess that you have to 'load' ( and by load I don't necessary mean to use $this->load->view(), but loading it with JS ) many different views, where each one will have a pagination, into a single main view. So I guess that you will have to use n-different methods in your controller where each one will hold the functionality of each pagination. Again haven't tested this.

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion Guyz.But Now onwards first test your solution code and then post it only if it is a Success.